# create search page which shows fields with MORE/HIDE option

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have search page which shows 12 fields initially.
Now want to add link as "MORE" to show 10 more fields including above fileds too.
When user clicks on "HIDE" those 10 option get vanish too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ajax` for that.

You can use Jquery for simpler ajax calls. [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).